# 'this' keyword in javascript returns differently

Tags: javascript

Why does the **`this`** keyword express different values in the following code?

```
var t = {
    a: "a",
    b: {
        c: "c",
        d: function () {
            return this;
        }
    },
    f: function () {
        return this;
    },
    g: this
}

var k = t.f(),
    l = t.g;

alert(k); // returns [object object] i.e 't'
alert(l); // returns [object DOMWindow] i.e 'window'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're used to some other programming languages like C++, Java, or C#, the first thing about understanding `this` in JavaScript is: It's completely different from `this` in those other languages, even though it looks very similar and sometimes even acts similarly.

When you're creating the `t` object, you capture the *value* of `this` as of when the object is created and store it in the property `g`. So `g` will be whatever `this` was when `t` was created. Because `this` refers to the global object (`window`, on browsers) by default unless you're using strict mode, that's what `t.g` will be.

In contrast, your `t.f` function is getting *called* and is returning the value of `this` that exists *within the call*. In JavaScript (for now), `this` is determined entirely by *how a function is called* rather than where it's defined. In particular, when you call a function as part of an expression that retrieved the function from a property reference, `this` is set to the object within the call. This is a complex way of saying when you do `t.f()`, during the call to `f`, `this` will be `t`.

Some further reading (on my blog):

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)